# Java. Конструктор, который использует сеттер - когда это нужно?

Tags: java, конструктор, setter

Встретил такую конструкцию в обучающем примере.

```
public class Vehicle {
  private String color;

 //Constructor
  Vehicle(String c) {
    this.setColor(c);
  }

  // Setter
  public void setColor(String c) {
    this.color = c;
  }
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, сеттер используют чтобы задать значение приватной переменной, на что способен и конструктор. Зачем использовать конструктор, который использует сеттер, который присвоит значение переменной, если можно обойтись конструктором? Бывают случаи когда это необходимо, или это просто теоритический пример что так можно?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Сеттер не всегда просто присваивает значение переменной, чаще всего он ещё выполняет какие-то действия(нормализует данные, например), поэтому чтобы не дублировать код из сеттера в конструкторе - можно просто вызывать сеттер из конструктора.

Comment: 1) То есть значение переменной, присвоенное в конструкторе при создании объекта уже никак не изменить? Не знал...

2) Про сеттеры пока знаю самую общую теорию, не знаю что значит "нормализовать данные". Но спасибо большое, буду иметь в виду.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin имелось в виду, что **приватную** переменную уже не изменить никак извне напрямую. Т.е. `Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle("red");`, то `vehicle.color = "green";` уже нельзя сделать без сеттера.......или метода данного класса, который будет внутри манипулировать сией переменной

Comment: 1) Значение **приватной** переменной, присвоенное в конструкторе при неимении сеттера изменить нельзя. При наличии сеттера их можно менять через него.

2) Ну, предположим, что Вам нужно присвоить значение Integer переменной, но Вам нужно чтобы она всегда была более 0 и менее 256. Для этого в сеттере можно проводить соответствующие проверки и преобразования, при этом в других местах кода не задумываясь об этом вызывать сеттер.

Comment: 1) Понял, я подумал что вообще невозможно изменить 2) Теперь понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: Первый пункт стоит удалить из ответа. Во-первых, он не относится к вопросу, во-вторых, в общем случае не верен.

Comment: При первом прочтении, мне показалось что вопрос состоял скорее в необходимости вообще использовать сеттеры, а не именно в конструкторе. Внес правку чтобы было понятнее при чтении ответа.

Comment: @AimX 1. Наличие сеттера оговорено в условии. Т.о. его не может не быть. 2. Речь исключительно про прямой доступ к переменной в конструкторе vs через сеттер. 3. Отсутствие сеттера никаким образом не относится к возможности изменения значения приватных переменных изнутри или извне.

Comment: Хорошо, поправлю ответ.

Answer (score 13):

Плохой обучающий пример. Я бы не рекомендовал использовать сеттеры внутри конструктора, особенно если сеттер простой. Если сеттер содержит много всего, то в этом случае лучше пересмотреть структуру класса, быть может, будет лучше использовать Билдер паттерн для создания экземпляра класса.
Главная проблема с сеттерами внутри конструктора (а точнее, с сеттерами, которые могут быть переопределены) это 
то, что они могут создать кучу проблем, если метод будет переопределен.

Цитата из книги JAVA:Эффективное программирование. 2е издание, Джошуа Блох. Статья 17.

> **Конструкторы класса не должны вызывать переопределяемые методы**, непосредственно или опосредованно. Нарушение этого правила может
>   привести к аварийному завершению программы. Конструктор суперкласса
>   выполняется прежде конструктора подкласса, а потому переопределяющий метод в подклассе будет вызываться перед запуском конструктора этого подкласса. И если переопределенный метод зависит от
>   инициализации, которую осуществляет конструктор подкласса, то этот
>   метод будет работать совсем не так, как ожидалось

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду иметь в виду, хотя пока не все понимаю.