# Java Конструктор который использует сеттер - как использовать инкапсуляцию, если это антипаттерн?

Tags: java, инкапсуляция, setter, антипаттерн

Столкнулся с такой дилеммой - с одной стороны сеттеры позволяют нам создавать проверки входных данных на корректность значений, а в случае сложной бизнес логики выполняются действия с входными данными прежде чем они запишутся в поля класса.
Однако, как я узнал чуть позже - использовать сеттеры в конструкторах является антипаттерном.

И как же тогда мне поступить, если нельзя использовать сеттеры, и это плохой тон программирования. - использовать логику в конструкторе можно, но тогда не понятен смысл инкапсуляции если проверки в сеттерах на корректность входных данных никак не повлияет на результат - либо проверка в конструкторе и сеттер вообще не при делах.

Можно, конечно сделать конструктор приватным, тогда данные будут поступать только через сеттеры. Не понимаю как использовать сеттеры на практике если нужно не только сокрытие данных, но и бизнеслогика на входе.

Comment: вы в конструкторе свои данные на валиднсть не проверяете что ли?

Comment: `использовать сеттеры в конструкторах является антипаттерном` источник этой инфы?

Comment: `Можно, конечно сделать конструктор приватным` это вам не поможет никак.

Comment: Да, столкнулся с этим когда понадобилась проверка на валидность. Это привело к не однозначным выводам о применении сеттеров. Аналогичный вопрос возникал на данном форуме - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539192/java-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: "нельзя использовать сеттеры" - Можно. Кто Вам может это запретить?

Comment: Про то что это антипаттерн на другом форуме https://overcoder.net/q/1018800/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5

Comment: Я понимаю, что никто не запретит, однако ели в крупной компании используют лучшие практики, то своим применением сеттеров в конструкторе будет наверно неграмотно, поэтому интересуюсь а как правильно?

Comment: @tym32167 , в общем, я так понял, что обычно сеттеры можно использовать в конструкторах. Но бывают конструкции, где нельзя, и таких случаев не много.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы избежать потенциальных проблем с кодом "Конструкторы класса не должны вызывать переопределяемые методы" (JAVA:Эффективное программирование. 2е издание, Джошуа Блох. Статья 17) я просто сделал сеттеры неизменяемыми (final), что защитит код и одновременно позволяет использовать сеттеры в конструкторах без опасения.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что если перед записью данных выполняется какая либо бизнес логика, то логично поместить её в приватный метод, и использовать его в и сеттере и в конструкторе.

Comment: А зачем в сеттер этот метод помещать ели он никак не повлияет на конструктор при создании экземпляра? Другое дело использовать статический метод( не сеттер) и поместить его в конструктор, но не проверял.

Comment: Хотя и в сеттер нужно тоже этот метод добавить. А это уже дублирование кода, что расстраивает. Но если это будет статика, то может и не потребуется.

Comment: Ты дублируешь лишь вызов метода в сеттере и в конструкторе. Сама бизнес логика описывается единожды в приватном методе